# The "derby" way of user authentication?

Tags: javascript, derbyjs

I know there are some packages like derby-auth, every-auth etc., that were written by the community/derby developers.

After a research I noticed that almost all the answers about the authentication mechanics in derby are pretty much a year old. Were there any changes? Is there a "derby" way to manage a simple username/password user authentication?

The official derby documentation says:

**Access control**
*A basic access control mechanism is implemented, but it isn’t documented quite yet. An example is coming soon.*

You can mix up your own authentication service, but the key point wold be - is there a way to properly secure you collections to prevent client side intrusion?

EDIT:
I can't find anywhere an example of a simple login and data lock! Is there a way to lock down collections and restrict some of the CRUD methods, like in MeteorJs? Right now, even with the derby-auth package, I am fully capable of mutating the model data trough the browser console, without being logged in.

**Such a great framework, but this leak of documentation destroys it all..**

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that is still work in progress: derby is still far from being production ready.

I'm working on a package called derby-passport, which is basically a fork of derby-auth, and I don't think any of these packages is actually an answer to you question. Not yet.

Comment: That's what I thought. Same story with MeteorJS (not authentication, but other problems), I moved on towards an API driven solution build on top of sockets.io. (SailsJS kinda like approach)

Comment: Liking the look of your auth package!

Comment: @DanieleSalatti ah..thanks for letting me know, I think Derby are coming out with their own soon..